# How should I properly give credit for an image I will use in a software application?

Tags: united-states, copyright, intellectual-property, software

I am making a computer application that I will receive payment for. I have found an image online with a creative commons license (CC BY) allowing it to be used for any purpose with attribution, and I wish to use this image in my program. I plan to say "[image name] image courtesy of [the creator] used under Creative Commons license" along with a link to their page in the README file. Is this appropriate attribution, or how could it be done better?

Comment: I'd put it in a separate "Credits" file and make it available under the "Help" menu. You should make it as available as reasonably possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [licence](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/deed.en) tells you what you must do:

> Attribution — You must give [appropriate credit](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/deed.en#), provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. **You may do so in any reasonable manner**, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.

I highlighted the important point: they tell you what you must do, the how is up to you so long as it is reasonable.